# what are the different attributes one can use for x-nav-link?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10, laravel-breeze

I recently installed Laravel Framework 10.43.0 and then installed Laravel Breeze into that, which created a bunch of new files, including resources/views/layouts/navigation.blade.php. In that file there's this:

```
<!-- Navigation Links -->
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ms-10 sm:flex">
    <x-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
    </x-nav-link>
</div>
```

I can add new nav links by adding new x-nav-link elements but my question is...  what are the valid `:` attributes for x-nav-link? There's `:href` and `:active`...  anything else?

I ask because I'd like to make a nav link appear conditionally based on whether or not you're an admin for the site and I'm curious if there's a built in way to do that with the x-nav-link element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than `:href` and `:active`, it also supports standard html attributes like `:class`, `:target` and any other anchor `<a>` tag specific attribute

While Laravel breeze does not have any built in attribute to handle protected link link in your case. You can use Laravel built-in authorization by implementing the `@can` blade directive which can be used like this in your code:

```
@can('admin')
<x-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
    {{ __('Dashboard') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

@endcan

You can add other protection depending on your need